# How to prevent dough from stopping food processor motor

Tags: dough

I have a [Cuisinart 7-cup food processor](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00004S9EM). Whenever I knead dough for milk buns in it, it'd get stuck after about 45 seconds. If I shut it off, it resets after about 10 minutes, but it's a PITA. Here's the recipe and amounts I use:

```
240g AP flour (about 2 cups)
10g wheat gluten
5g instant yeast
3g salt
35g sugar
1 egg
40g butter
120g milk
3g white vinegar
```

The food processor doesn't get stuck with other doughs I've made (French bread and pizza). I'd prefer not to have to take the dough and the blade out every time it gets stuck, since that's a pain too. Any pointers? Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like this dough is more than your food processor can handle.  You might try making a half batch, or if you have a quality stand mixer, adapting the recipe for its dough hook.

Comment: Hm, I dismissed that possibility since it has no problem kneading a dough that's 300g AP flour and 300g water, which exceeds the problematic dough in both weight and volume. But it's worth a try, thanks!

Comment: Note that the dough you have problems with is at a hydration of about 50% (with extra gluten), and the dough you have no trouble with is at a hydration of 100%, so it is going to be much softer.  Its not just the total volume, its the thickness of the dough.

Comment: are you using the metal blade, or a plastic dough blade?  some of the plastic blades have a higher clearance from the bottom ... Mark Bittman's broiche recipe gives my food processor problems because it's so sticky and calls for the metal blade.

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ recommend you turn those comments into an answer.  The reason it gets stuck _is_ the low hydration level (even a stand mixer sometimes chokes at tough dough) and the solution _is_ to run two batches.  Even though the cuisinart 7-cup isn't weak.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like this dough is more than your food processor can handle. You might try making a half batch, or if you have a quality stand mixer, adapting the recipe for its dough hook.

In the comments to the question, you mentioned another dough that you do not have trouble with.

Note that the dough you have problems with is at a hydration of about 50% (with extra gluten), and the dough you have no trouble with is at a hydration of 100%, so it is going to be much softer. Its not just the total volume, its the thickness of the dough.  The softer dough will give much less resistance to the food processor.

(Hydration is the amount of water in the recipe, expressed as a percentage of the weight of flour, so 1000 g of flour and 600 grams or mL of water would be a 60% hydration.)

Answer (score 0):

I make several types dough, both for bread/pizza and fresh pasta. In the past I noticed that my mixers where getting a bit overloaded when any of the following ingredients were added:

- wheat gluten
- eggs
- non refined flours

Or, like other mentioned, obviously when lower hydration occurs.

Just an example: I own an old school Simac MX700 pasta machine and I was able to crack open the extruding mechanism trying to make a 99% egg and semolina dough! It took me about three months of hammer and screwdrivers to be able to completely rip it apart the same piece of plastic and fix the machine!

In your case I would try to:

- increase the quantity of milk by 10-20% and increase the cooking time by 3-7 minutes (you'll need to try a few times to get it right) to obtain the same level of evaporation
- beat the egg with one teaspoon of water before adding it to the mix

*Or solve the problem forever like I did, with an Electrolux Assistent! :)
(just kidding, hopefully this wont start a flame!)*

Comment: Yep, increasing liquid was the other thing I'm going to try. Will let everyone know if that works! I should mention my 100% hydration dough (that the Cuisinart has no problem with) has 10g extra gluten too.